# Crystal Report- Please wait while the document is being processed

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2022

### Highlights

→ Recently Upgraded from VS2008 (Integrated Crystal Report) to VS2022.
→ VS2022 auto upgraded **Crystal Report 2008** to **Crystal Report SP33 for VS2022** (installed manually).

### Problem

All reports are working as before except one **Crystal Report**. It shows the below message.

[image]
**Error**: Please wait while the document is being processed.

Even after 30 min of waiting the error persists.

**BUT**

If instead of displaying i directly print it then there is no problem.
STRANGE!!!!

### Things I have Tried

1. Tried *removing one field* at a time.
   **Result**: Error persists
2. Tried *removing all fields in the report* and leaving the report blank.
   **Result**: Error persists
3. Tried *removing database* from the report and removing all the older fields and leaving the report blank.
   **Result**: Error persists
4. [Youtube Solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qNd8pPnFl0) which says check version in registry under

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports

and check if **CRRuntime32Version** and **CRRuntimeMSMVersion** has same Crystal Report version under it.
**Result**: I only have **CRRuntime32Version** Key available in it and it has right version written in it **13.0.33**

### Need Help

Reconstructing the Crystal Report is the last option but will take so much time as this is a legacy code. Please let me know if you have come across solution for such a problem.

### Edit 1

Code for Crystal Report displaying

```
ReportDocument Rpt = new ReportDocument();
Rpt = new Forms.Printing.Rpt_Sales();
Rpt.PrintOptions.PaperSource = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSource.Auto;
Rpt.Refresh();

crystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = Rpt;
crystalReportViewer2.Refresh();
```

For the moment removed **DataSource** as no fields are present. Still the error persists.

### Edit 2

Technology used

1. VS2022
2. Crystal Report SP33
3. Language: C#
4. Platform: Winform (Windows Form)